# Spring JSP Select List for Range of Numbers

Tags: spring, jsp, select

I'm creating a time entry system where the user has the option of selecting the hour and minute via two separate drop down select boxes. So the hour box has the numbers **1-12** in it, and the minute box has **00-59**.

This is part of a Spring 2.5 Java EE project.

I have this in my JSP, for example, to create the option values as part of a select dropdown list:

```
<% for( int i=1; i<=12; i++) { %>
<option value="<%=i %>" <%= Integer.parseInt(time1fromHr)==i?selected:"" %> />
<% } %>
```

The for loop generates all the hours and marks the currently selected hour as default. Well, it looks pretty ugly to me, mostly because there is quite a bit of Java code involved here and I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to approaching this problem using JSP tags or the Spring library. I am passing in the currently set parameters via the ModelAndView object in Spring.

Comment: it would probably look prettier if you unrolled the loop and just had 12 statements with the hour hard-coded plus the hour check in jsp

Comment: Disagree- I mean remember that you have to be able to select the option that is already selected which means every single minute needs to check if it is "the one"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model you could pass a List of Integers for hours, and another for minutes.  Then you could use the form:select tag.

```
<form:select path="hour">
  <form:options items="${hours} />
</form:select>
```

If your command object for the form has the selected value set in the "hour" value, and the model contains 1-12 in the "hours" value, then it should render the select and take care of marking the appropriate option selected.  Then you do the same for minutes.

If you don't want to go the spring form taglib direction, you could again place the hours in the model and use JSTL.  Something like:

```
<c:forEach var="hour" items="${hours}">
  <c:if test="${hour} == ${selectedHour}">
    <option value="${hour}" selected="selected">${hour}</option>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${hour} != ${selectedHour}">
    <option value="${hour}" >${hour}</option>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

I know there's a better way to do the c:if part, maybe using a c:choose, but you get the gist.  You have your selected value in selectedHour and your choices in hours in the model.

Comment: I like this solution, mostly because I am not yet a strong Spring person, thanks!

Comment: Although I think it would be better to use <c:choose>/<c:otherwise> here... but whatevs

Comment: yep, and I mentioned that at the bottom of my answer. I'm not actively using JSP much these days and was short on time so I just put the c:if in there to get the point across.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, this part of Spring MVC:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/index.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String form(ModelMap map) {
        Map<String,String> country = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
    country.put("US", "United Stated");
    country.put("CHINA", "China");
    country.put("SG", "Singapore");
    country.put("MY", "Malaysia");
    map.addAttribute("countryList", country);
        return "index";
}
```

and then use:

```
<form:select path="country" items="${countryList}" />
```

don't forget to add Spring type Library to your page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSTL for comparison

```
<c:forEach var="hour" items="${hours}">
  <c:if test="${hour == selectedHour}">
    <option value="${hour}" selected="selected">${hour}</option>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${hour != selectedHour}">
    <option value="${hour}" >${hour}</option>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>

OR 

<c:forEach var="hour" items="${hours}">
  <c:if test="${hour eq selectedHour}">
    <option value="${hour}" selected="selected">${hour}</option>
  </c:if>
  <c:if test="${hour ne selectedHour}">
    <option value="${hour}" >${hour}</option>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```